# Get the latest record of datetime field by date value

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like

```
id    |    start                |    Value   | Value2    | Value3
1     |    2019-01-01 22:15:02  |    A       |   P       |   C
2     |    2019-01-01 22:35:23  |    B       |   O       |   G
4     |    2019-01-02 22:35:36  |    C       |   D       |   H
5     |    2019-01-02 22:37:15  |    D       |   C       |   F
7     |    2019-01-03 17:26:36  |    C       |   K       |   M
10    |    2019-01-03 12:05:15  |    D       |   J       |   L
```

I have a lot of records for the same **day**, but different **time**.
I need to select the latest of each `day` from a `DateTime` field.
It should return the records of IDs:

```
id: 2 for Jan 1   
id: 5 for Jan 2nd  
id: 7 for January 3rd
```

Tried without success:

```
SELECT value, value2, value3
FROM myTable AS mt
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, MAX(start)
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY start
) AS b ON mt.id = b.id
```

I get no errors, but the data are mixed up. It shows the latest dateTime value, but the rest of the fields (Value, value2, value3) are wrong. They don't match with the latest row.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible solutions:

```
SELECT mt.<columns>
FROM myTable AS mt
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT DATE(start) as start_date, MAX(start) AS start
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY DATE(start)
) AS b ON mt.start = b.start;
```

I like to use an exclusion join. Look for another row with a greater start datetime on the same date. The no such row exists, then `mt` must have the greatest time for a given date.

```
SELECT mt.<columns>
FROM myTable AS mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable AS mt2
  ON DATE(mt.start) = DATE(mt2.start) AND mt.start < mt2.start
WHERE mt2.start IS NULL;
```

You can also use a window function if you're using MySQL 8.0:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT mt.<columns>,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(start) ORDER BY start DESC) AS rownum
    FROM myTable AS mt
) AS b
WHERE b.rownum = 1;
```